# Best approach for "game" problematic

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I have to tell you, I'm completely NEW to XNA, and I know NOTHING about vertex, multisampling, etc etc..

However, I love so much programming and windows phone that I wanted to start an immense challenge... create a XNA game! :D

ok, let's stop the story and start explaining..

I'm making a big game... which I've worked for it for almost 1 month, now it's almost over..

I've just a big issue, which is the central point of the game... think about it as a 1024x800 puzzle, each point of puzzle can be clicked, and when it's clicked it must change color..

so we have 2 hard point to do,
1) UNDERSTAND WHICH PIECE I'VE CLICKED
2) COLOR THIS PIECE

I thought about 2 approaches

**FIRST APPROACH**

- 1 PNG big puzzle background 1024x800
- N PNG for each puzzle piece, with transparent layer around the piece ( each piece is 1024x800, in the correct position )

by merging the N+1 PNGS we have the complete puzzle, now, it's REALLY easy to understand which piece I've clicked, because I just have to cycle the N textures, and when I got the one which havent the transparent pixel in the point clicked, I've the piece!
then, for color it, I've just to color the texture in the draw part.

it's easy, the problem is that if I have to drag, zoom, 50*4 pngs, it's really slow :(

**SECOND APPROACH**

- 1 PNG big puzzle 1024x800 with all pieces merged, EACH piece will have a different color fill, example, 1) 250,250,250  2) 245,245,245 etc
- After the PNG has been loaded, I calculate the pixel indexes by using GetData for each piece and store it in an array for each piece

for getting the piece selected, it's easy.. I've just to calculate the y*width+x and get the piece with that value on the array.

problem is that when I've to color.. I've to iterate the array and change the RGB and then finally do a SetData.. it takes 1 second to colorate that piece.. it MAY be acceptable.. but I want better ...

second approach is way MUCH MUCH MUCH faster when dragging and zooming, because it's only 1 PNG, and I can use bigger resolutions thanks to this, this far way best approach

any suggestions??

Thanks,

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a 1024x800 puzzle, with each pixel being a piece? You are not going to want to make 819200 image files or define 819200 individual behaviors for each pixel.

You need to (well, *should*) use object-oriented concepts for this. Here is a basic idea of the path I think you should take:

1. Define a "Piece" class. This Piece represents a game piece.
2. In the Piece class, define a rectangle which represents this piece on the board. If your piece is an irregular shape (like an S tetronimo, etc), define multiple rectangles. If you have multiple different types of pieces (and different shapes), you will want to use inheritance and make each different type of piece inherit from the Piece class, but define its own rectangles. However, if your 'pieces' are just pixels on the screen, just make a 1x1 Rectangle.
3. Fill the rectangles with a color using SpriteBatch. You can use a single white pixel png and stretch it to fill the rectangle(s) as well as specify the color.
4. Use the rectangles to hit-test your pieces with touch. If a touch falls within your rectangle, you have selected that piece. If your pieces are only 1 pixel in size, it's even easier: simply lookup the piece at the touch position's X and Y values.
5. Now for the game board: depending on the shape and possible positions of the pieces, you will need to select a way to store them. If all your pieces were squares, you could store them in a 2D array. Otherwise you might use a map, where the key is the piece's position and the value is the piece itself.

A basic summary of this approach: don't try to store your board in a single texture. Writing/reading texture data is slow and textures are not made to act as data structures. Instead, store your pieces as individual objects. Iterate through each piece and draw it to the screen.

Comment: of course I'm using full object oriented concept on doing this.. I was just talking abstractly for describing the problem.. I like your path, but, what if a piece is a completely irregular form, with curves and more, how can I make multiple rectangles for this? The graphics designer made me a PNG with the pieces, and these pieces aren't really regular as you can see here (yes, it's groenlandy) http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/94/grobn.png/

Comment: Oh, well. It would have been helpful to know the shapes of the 'puzzle pieces' you were using. How exactly are you going to be fitting these together?

Comment: they're already fitted and in position, I don't need to move them singly, just click and color them

Comment: Alright, I guess this is a more specifically challenging situation than I imagined. Firstly, I'd suggest cropping the pngs as much as possible to save on memory space. Then, determine the positioning of the images on the board and save that to a readonly array of Vector2s. Reference this array to place the pieces on the board. Other than that it would be pretty much your first option (color the pieces in the Draw call). I still think you need to avoid using pixel data as much as possible. Consider defining a group of rectangles or circles to approximate the continent shape.

Comment: Cropping or using transparent layer shouldnt be that different, or I am wrong? determining pièce position is too much complicated and long.. Second way is much more complicated to do but, except the coloring part, way MUCH more nicer and incredibly fast

Comment: As a general rule I always favor doing more work during the development of a game in order to have the game do less work. As in, if I know exactly where the pieces will be, I'm going to crop the images down as much as possible and hard-code the positions in, so that the game uses less memory. If I know the shape of the pieces, I'm going to sit down and hard-code some hitboxes which fit them instead of making the game do expensive pixel-testing. Consider it this way: if you're going through an array of hitboxes, that's O(n), but if you're going through the X and Y of a texture that's O(n^2).

Comment: ...on top of that, if you don't crop your textures at all, you could be adding 200% or more pixels to that calculation. That's a lot of pixel testing. I'd encourage you, if you decide to do pixel testing, at least crop the piece images. Or, when the game loads, iterate through all the pixels and store the locations of the non-transparent ones, then find an efficient way to check if the pixel the user pressed is in the list.

Comment: you were right, CROPPING was the way, I Thought that image with transparent layer had the same weight of a cropped one, thanks.

Comment: Nope, the png file will still store data for every pixel, transparent or not. Glad I could help in some way.